# How integrate uwp app into context menu of windows explorer for jpg?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to integrate my app into the windows explorer. The users should be able to select more than one image and call from the context menue the option “resize”.
Therefore I created the following windows.fileTypeAssociation

```
   <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="bla" >
        <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          <uap3:Verb Id="Resize" Extended="false" MultiSelectModel="Player">Resize</uap3:Verb>
          <uap3:Verb Id="Edit1" Extended="false" MultiSelectModel="Player">Edit1</uap3:Verb>
        </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.banana</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.foo</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
```

If the user right clicks on a .jpg or .txt file the context menu doesn’t contain the menu items “Resize” and “Edit1”. On the opposite it works for files with the extension .banana and .foo. The banana file typ extension is associated with another uwp app named bananaedit. The extension .foo is only related to my app. Why can’t I associate or integrate my context menu items with .jpg or txt filetypes?

How integrate uwp app into context menu of windows explorer for jpg?

<strike>[EDIT]
Uservoice request for [Allow context menu verbs with file explorer integration without setting the app as default for the file type](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35467633-allow-context-menu-verbs-with-file-explorer-integr)</strike>

[Edit2] upvote this feature here (Feedbackhub) [integrate context menu into windows explorer 4 #uwp](https://aka.ms/AA6rmrk)
[Edit3] upvote this feature on github [ProjectReunion](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjectReunion/issues/56)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have any problems with your code. You just need to make some change on your device default app settings.

In your device, it has installed the system application **Photos** app and it is also the default app for the **.jpg** file type in your device, the **Photos** app doesn't include the **Resize** and **Edit1** options, so when you right click the **.jpg** file, the context menu doesn’t contain the menu items "Resize" and "Edit1", so as the **.txt** file format whose default file type app is **Notepad**.

As for the **.foo** and **.banana** file types, your app has been set as default app for these file type automatically when you app associate the file type(your app maybe the only one which associates the file type), so you can see the "Resize" and "Edit1" options when you right click the  **.foo** and **.banana** file.

You can check this on your device Settings app => Apps => Default apps => Choose default apps by file type as the following image,

[image]

So if you want the context menu contain your menu items "Resize" and "Edit1" when right cick the .jpg or .txt file, you should direct the user to set your app as the default app of the .jpg and .txt file type. You can use the [launch Apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) to provide the user a convenient link to the privacy settings for that resource, see the topic [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

Comment: Too bad, I don't want to replace the Photos app and I think most of the users don't want to start the resize app when they try to open a jpg. Maybe I can set my app as default and detect how the app was started. If the user doesn't start the uwp app by the context menu, I would use Launch Api and start the Photos app and close my resize app immediately. Not sure if this can work in practice.